# Spring Boot Version Upgrade

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have update my `Spring Boot Project` with Latest `Spring Boot Version 2.3.1.RELEASE` but after that I am started facing below error regarding dependency -

```
package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist
package org.apache.commons.collections does not exist
```

and also I am getting error for `lombok`

I check `Spring Boot Version 2.3.1.RELEASE` release notes but I did not found any specific changes for this

***Update***

I am upgrading from `1.5.x to 2.3.1.RELEASE`

I solve the dependency issue but now I am facing below issue

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:157)
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:98)
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:64)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
```

below is my `build.gradle` dependancies

```
dependencies {
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
//compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-docs'
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-feign'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
 compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix'
 compile 'com.newrelic.agent.java:newrelic-api:4.2.0'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version:   '3.1'
compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections',  version: '3.2.2'

compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.6.1'
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.6.1'
compile 'com.netflix.feign:feign-okhttp:8.18.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'

compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.9.1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.1'
compile 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'){
 exclude module : 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc'
}
compile 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
compile 'com.h2database:h2'
compile 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.2.4'
compile 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:3.4.2'

compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.10.0'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.10.0'
testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.8.0'
testCompile 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:3.0.3'
testCompile 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:2.8.0'
testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-  test:2.3.1.RELEASE'
}
```

Comment: From what spring boot version did you update? 1.5, 2.0, 2.09...etc

Comment: Can you share the part of the part of the poom file where you have "org.apache.commons" added? the full stack trace including the caused by?

Comment: If you are using an IDE you might want to try and refresh your build model, if you have not done so yet.

Comment: Also, there's a random whitespace in your second-to-last line.

Comment: It looks like the version of Spring Cloud you're using isn't compatible with Boot 2.3.1. Showing dependency versions would be helpful. You should be using the Spring Cloud Hoxton release train, as shown in the table on this page: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I solved the above issue but now I am facing `java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set` in my controller test case. In my test case I am using `mockMvc.perform(patch(URI).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(request)))
            .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))`

but `org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8;` is deprecated. I tried `application/json` but still same error